# Remove Oldest File in Repository

Tags: linux, git, bash

I've got a git repo, and I have revisions of a file, dated with a unix timestamp. I want to get the oldest file (I.E. the one with the smallest timestamp) and remove it.

Is this possible with Bash alone and if so, how?

Comment: So... you want to deliberately destroy the repo?

Comment: They're builds. I don't want to waste all my repo space by continually uploading builds.

Comment: That's why you put them in the ignore file.

Comment: I want them uploaded, but I want to remove old ones that have already been uploaded.

Comment: If you change one commit, any commit based on that one will be rewritten, so all repositories will have to pull in a new commit history from the changed point. Is that acceptable?

Comment: I'm not sure what this question has to do with `git`.  As far as I can tell, you're asking, "how do I find the oldest file in a directory tree?"  Am I reading the question correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find the oldest file in a directory tree, you can do something like this:

```
ls -tr $(find . -type f) | head -1
```

This works as long as the number of files isn't too large. It's even easier if you're willing to delete "all files older than a certain number of days".  For example, if you want to get rid of anything older than 5 days:

```
find . -type f -mtime +5 -print | xargs rm
```

You wouldn't want to run this verbatim; you'd want to provide the appropriate filters to `find` -- or root it at the approriate directory -- so that you're only deleting files you really want to delete.

Obviously you'll need to commit these deletes to git as well.  You could do something like this:

```
find . -type f -mtime +5 -print | xargs git rm
git commit -m "deleted things"
```

...although note that this could commit changes that you've previously staged with "git add".  Some things are best done by hand.